# Why does the console tell me uncaught in promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a fetch request to delete some lists from my backend, but the console is giving me a complaint. The console says "Uncaught (in promise)."

This is my fetch() in the frontend:

```
  const handleClickGarbage = (key) => { // for deleting a grocery list
    const temp = loginUserr;

    try {
      console.log('inside click garbage');
      const accessToken = temp.accessToken;
      console.log(accessToken);
      const param = key;
      console.log(param);

      fetch(`http://localhost:3010/v0/grocerylists?listName=${param}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        }),
      })
        .then((results) => {
          if (!results.ok) {
            throw results;
          }
          console.log(results);
          getCurrentGroceryListTabInfo(); // get the current tab info again because we just updated the info
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

This is my user.js:

```
exports.deleteGroceryList = async (req, res) => {
  const listNamee = req.query.listName;
  const memberIdd = req.userID;
  console.log('inside delete gl');
  console.log(listNamee);
  console.log(memberIdd);

  const deleted = await db.deleteGroceryList(listNamee, memberIdd);
  console.log('user.js line 286)\n');
  console.log(deleted);
  if (deleted === null) {
    res.status(400).send();
  } else {
    console.log('user.js line 292)\n');
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
};
```

This is my db.js:

```
exports.deleteGroceryList = async (listNamee, memberIdd) => {
  const listName = listNamee;
  const memberId = memberIdd;

  const select = 'DELETE FROM grocery_list WHERE list_name = $1 AND member_id = $2 RETURNING *';
  const query = {
    text: select,
    values: [listName, memberId],
  };

  const {rows} = await pool.query(query);
  console.log('db.js line 495)\n');
  console.log(rows);

  if (rows.length > 0) {
    return rows.length;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

And this is my openapi.yaml:

```
  /grocerylists:
    delete:
      description: Deletes a grocery list from user's existing grocery lists'
      security:
      - bearerAuth: [] 
      parameters:
        - name: listName
          in: query
          description: name of grocery list to delete
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Removed list from grocery lists successfully
        401:
          description: Unauthorised
        400:
          description: Bad Request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
```

I suspect it is something wrong with my api because console.logging results in the front end shows that user.js returned a status code of 200.:
[image]

But then the console also says uncaught promise:
[image]

Comment: Because you don't handle the `throw results;` exception anywhere. `try`/`catch` works only when you `await` the promise instead of using `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

You used `.then()` syntax to handle Promise. When you choose to use `.then()` syntax, you should catch the error with `.catch()`, and you don't have that in your code. Just add `catch()` method to a Promise that `fetch` returns.

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:3010/v0/grocerylists?listName=${param}`, {
  method: 'DELETE',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
  ),
})
.then((results) => {
  if (!results.ok) {
    throw results;
  }
  console.log(results);
  getCurrentGroceryListTabInfo(); // get the current tab info again because we just updated the info
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error)
});
```